# How to import a class from a different package in a groovy file

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have a gradle file whose root directory is set as (from the settings.gradle file)

```
rootProject.name = 'PackageX'
```

In a groovy test I am trying to access a class in a different package.

```
    def setup(){
        mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDb)
        DynamoDBTableMapper<?, ?, ?> amazonDynamoDBMapper = mapper.newTableMapper(Entity.class)
    }
```

Here the Entity.class is in 'PackageY', because of which I am getting the error

> unable to resolve class com.mainpackage.sub1.sub2.PackageY.sub11.sub12.

Adding an import statement with the below line gives cannot resolve error

```
import com.mainpackage.sub1.sub2.PackageY.sub11.sub12.sub13.Entity
```

Package Statement above Entity.class is

```
package com.mainpackage.sub1.sub2.PackageY.sub11.sub12.sub13
```

Folder Structure is like

```
| -PackageY
|  -src
|   -main
|    -java
|     -com.mainpackage.sub1.sub2.PackageY
|      -sub11
|       -sub12
|        -sub13
|         -Entity.java
```

Can someone please suggest what is the right way to access cross package class files in groovy test cases.

Comment: are you trying to import Entity.java or Entity.class? Is it located in jar or just in folder? how you starting groovy? have you jar/folder with Entity into classpath for your groovy script?  what package is declared inside the Entity.jar?

Comment: "are you trying to import Entity.java or Entity.class?" - In Java and Groovy there is no such thing as importing a `.java` file.  You can only import classes (and class like things like interfaces, records, enum, etc).  You can't import a `.java` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here the Entity.class is in 'PackageY'

If `Entity` is in a package named `PackageY` then you would need to refer to the class by its fully qualified name `PackageY.Entity` or provide an appropriate import statement at the top of the file after your own package statement.  That import statement could be `import PackageY.Entity` or `import PackageY.*`.

*Note that it non-standard for package names to include upper case letters and even more non standard to begin with an upper case letter.*

**UPDATE**

The question has been updated to indicate that `Entity` is in the `com.mainpackage.sub1.sub2.PackageY.sub11.sub12.sub13` package, so the import statements I mentioned above would be `import com.mainpackage.sub1.sub2.PackageY.sub11.sub12.sub13.*` or `import com.mainpackage.sub1.sub2.PackageY.sub11.sub12.sub13.Entity`.

Comment: import statement is not able to be resolved from package X. I updated the question. Please check.

Comment: Can you show me the `package` statement that is near the top of `Entity.java` and what is the source directory path in which `Entity.java` lives?